# How to encapsulate HTTP requests to APIs on Android in a clean way

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I don't have code to show, I am still trying to figure out how to do things. So I read a lot of things about threads on android, and the solutions I have. My app will be quite simple, I'll have one activity that gets information from a rest API and displays content accordingly.

The way I would like to do things :
-Have a model class to store the data I need from the API
-Have a service class wrapping my API call, taking care of auth and API parameters, performing the HTTP request, most likely using an AsyncTask.
-Have a service class encapsulating the API class and handling the cache and keeping a data structure up to date.

My UI will be an activity containing a ViewPager, displaying some Fragment that will be getting the information from my Service.

Now my problem is that I would like to avoid using too many listeners or callbacks to move up the hierarchy. In other works I would like to avoid having my API Service calling back my "ModelManager", himself calling back my UI ( Using Observer or so ). And I would also like to avoid passing objects that don't make sense and keep my interfaces clean somehow.

I hope I have been a little clear, but a more general question would be, how would one design classes around this kind of project ? My problem seems to be the HTTP call and the fact that I need to run it asynchronously. I thought about having the thread launched at the UI level, but it makes things much harder since my "ModelManager" is then accessed in a thread, and I need my UI to access it as well. So I thought I would encapsulate the HTTP call deep in my hierarchy so that I don't need to take care of this while developing the UI.

Any hint would be appreciated !

Comment: Take a look at http://square.github.io/retrofit/. It also supports RxJava (for observables etc).

Comment: Say, the problem I have in the design is not really to implement Observer. I actually want to avoid using it. I would like to avoid having my Service classes having to implement methods that are not part of their behavior, but I feel that the Asynchronous nature of the job they perform might force me into it.

For example, my ModelManager can't possibly return any value to the UI before having an answer from the API manager, therefore I need a cascade of callbacks somehow. If I am not clear enough I'll scribble a little diagram later to expose the problem visually.

Comment: I think your description is clear, I will elaborate on my previous comment in an answer. That'll take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have enough time right now to write an answer. I'll do that later on. In the mean time, to loosely couple components, you could take a look at [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: I had a look, I'll have to go through the examples tonight. I'm not sure I exactly understand it. At a first glance it looks like an Observer pattern. In the examples they give on the website they don't tell where should the annotated methods be located.  
Probably the sample code provided on github will help me understand the benefits of it.

Comment: I quickly give an update, I found an article that seems to expose the problem. I haven't had time to read it through yet, but I will. It can be found [here](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/otto.html).